# Access SQL left join - access removes parenthesis

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join

I have written a SQL query that do what I want:

```
SELECT 
    Tag.ID, Tag.Type, COUNT(Cable.Type) 
FROM 
    Tag 
LEFT JOIN 
    Cable ON (Cable.Type = Tag.Type AND Cable.Use = "KW")
GROUP BY 
    TagID, Tag.Type
```

Problem is that upon saving, MS Access removes the parenthesis around the `ON` clause. When I try to reopen the query, I cannot get the table as the query is not working without parenthesis. Also, I cannot edit the SQL as the query isn't working.

Q1: Are there any ways I can prevent Access from removing the parenthesis?

Q2: Any suggestions on how to reformulate the SQL to avoid the problem? I have tried the following:

```
SELECT 
    Tag.ID, Tag.Type, COUNT(Cable.Type) 
FROM 
    Tag 
LEFT JOIN 
    Cable ON Cable.Type = Tag.Type
WHERE 
    Cable.Use = "KW" OR Cable.Use Is Null
GROUP BY 
    TagID, Tag.Type
```

But, this takes away the entries of table "Tag" without matching entries in table "Cable", and I don't wont that; I want the counting to show "0" in these cases.

I know it is possible to force the sql query with the parenthesis into Access using VBA, but it is cumbersome to do often, and I have many of the similar cases.

Comment: You want `OR Cable.Use Is Null`.

Comment: Sure, edited now. However, that doesn't solve the problem. (My "actual" query had "Is Null", but I wrote simplified version of query here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    Tag.ID, Tag.Type,
    NZ((SELECT COUNT(Cable.Type) 
    FROM Cable
    WHERE Cable.Type = Tag.Type
    AND Cable.Use = "KW"),0)
FROM Tag
```

Comment: Excellent, that worked! Thank you very much for your effort and time!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Nz](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Nz-Function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c) function to resolve null entries

```
SELECT Tag.ID, Tag.Type, nz(COUNT(Cable.Type),0)
FROM Tag LEFT JOIN Cable ON Cable.Type = Tag.Type
WHERE nz(Cable.Use,"KW") = "KW"
GROUP BY TagID, Tag.Type
```

Comment: This gives fewer results than my original query with parenthesis around the "ON" clausule, so I assume this still omits entries from "Tag" without matching entries from "Cable"